# in Dplyr/Tidyverse, I can't figure out how to compare the sum of lets say said Name variable with the next the sum of the next?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

- For example, so far i've been able to compare using lead() and lag() for comparing the Tim's 3 points on jan-1 with let's say Tim's  1 point on jan-3, but I don't can't figure out how to do like sum of Tim's points across a a week as a new mutate() variable....
- Date: Jan 1 - May 1
- Name Variables: 5: John, Tim, Mike, Cath, Jake.
- Point Variables: Range: 0 - 50

Questions:

- Over Entire Date period:

  - What's each name variables sum compared to last week.
  - If the name scored 0 points in the entire week, use NA.

What i've tried This works by comparing daily sessions with previous week, and next week. Need to figure out how to compare sum of sessions instead of just daily sessions.

````
```
 df_weekly_sum_comparision <- df %>%
 group_by(names) %>%
 mutate(next_week = lead(points, order_by = date, n = 7))%>%
 mutate(last_week = lag (points, order_by = date, n = 7))%>%
 mutate(next_month = lead(points, order_by = date, n = 28))%>%
 mutate(last_month = lag (points, order_by = date, n = 28))%>%
 View()
```
````

Comment: Please p[rivide relecvant sample data using `dput`. Also, a desired output (also with `dput`) would help a lot.

Comment: Welcome, noxwei. Your question sounds intriguing, but with no data, it's quite hard to follow. Would you consider editing with a replicable example of your problem and desired solution?